# How to insulate banana tree during winter

Tags: fruit-trees, overwintering, winter, protection, banana

I have several banana trees in the ground at my place in northeastern Mississippi. They are about 2-5 feet tall. I would really like to salvage the stem during the winter if possible. What is the best way to do this?

Someone suggested cutting off the leaves and wrapping fiberglass and a tarp around it, but I don’t know either way if this is a good idea or not.

I hope to find a quick solution using materials I can buy at Lowe’s.

Comment: what is the lowest temperature you are expecting? is the site sheltered from winds?

Comment: Maybe 20 degrees or higher. Doesn’t get that cold here, but definitely goes below 32. High winds aren’t an issue. @kevinskio

Comment: I use bamboos and a lot of leaves. But some winters plant will die, just they grow (also in case of hard freeze) back next year (smaller)

Answer (score 1):

We live in Indiana. It can get 20 below.  Our trees are out all year and triple the next.  We don't cut the leaves. Let them brown and they will fall and insulate your plants. If you cut them before winter they will freeze. Water will get in stem and freeze inside. I would love to send you a picture of our banana tree forest surrounding our house. They are as tall as our second story.
Hope this helps