# How to encourage banana trees to grow after insulating over winter

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, tree-care, overwintering, banana

I have a few banana trees ([How to insulate banana tree during winter](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/61480/how-to-insulate-banana-tree-during-winter)) that I insulated with fiberglass over the winter in northern Mississippi. Two have started growing leaves. The others haven’t, but are still alive. See below for an example. Besides waiting, is there anything I can do to encourage them to grow?

[image]